# SQL two count for the field

Tags: sql

My table is,

```
 customdata check service loc value
  101        0    0        4   4
  101        0    0        3   3
  101        5     4       4    3
  102        0     0       1     2
  102        4     4       3     3
  103        0     0       4     4
```

My result should be like,

```
  customdata cnt splcnt//count of check when not 0
   101        3    1
   102        2    1
   103        1    0
```

Can anyone tell me how should i have my query to take this both this count.

Comment: questions like this will be easier to answer if you go on sqlfiddle.com and create table(s) to run the sql against

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement to conditionally `SUM` based on the value of `check`:

```
SELECT
    customdata,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN check > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS splcnt
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY customdata
```

Comment: I tried this,it never works,select count(customdata) as CNT, customdata,
                   SUM(CASE WHEN check > 0 THEN 1 END) AS splcnt,
                  sum(locationrating) as loc,sum(cleanlinessrating) as cle,
                  sum(valueformoneyrating) as val,sum(kitchenequipmentrating) as kit
                  from feedback group by customdata HAVING customdata!='null'AND customdata!='';

Comment: @Indira Please update your question to include the code that you've tried; also, please clarify what you mean by "never works".  Does it throw an error?  Does it not return the values that you were expecting?  If it doesn't return what you expected, in what way is the result different from what you were expecting?  Lastly, `HAVING` is used as a filter for aggregated values... I think a `WHERE` clause would be more appropriate in that query.

Comment: @Michael Maybe it's better to add an ELSE (`SUM(CASE WHEN [check] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS splcnt`) because without it the splcnt value for '103' is NULL (not 0).

Comment: @GmG Good point... if there are only `NULL` values, then the `SUM` will be `NULL` as you say... updated to include the `ELSE`.

Answer (score 1):

table name = tcustomdata, check col renamed to chck

```
SELECT a.customdata, a.cnt AS CNT_ALL, c.cnt AS chckcnt
FROM (SELECT customdata, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tcustomdata GROUP BY customdata) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT customdata, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tcustomdata WHERE chck != 0 GROUP BY customdata) c
ON a.customdata = c.customdata
```

check it out on [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b05/3)

Comment: thanks for the upvote, however, the other answer is hands down better, i admit